# Updating existing disk size on google cloud

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

I have disk of space  10G in google cloud with name disk1.

Root persistent disk has already occupied around  4 to 5 GB and remaining 5 GB is occupied by other  programs ,so it is almost full to 10GB .MY case is I can not add other disk ,i have to work on same disk.

I want to increase this disk  size from 10 GB to 20 GB,In **https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd** i can not see way of increasing size of existing disk in my case increasing size of disk1 to 20GB   **Is it  possible to update existing  disk  size ?**

Comment: in console where it shows that how much disk is in use and how much is left ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to replicate your issue and there is a workaround for this. Basically what you need to do is snapshot your disk, increase it, create a new instance with the new size.

From the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/):

1. create a snapshot of your disk (Compute > Compute Engine > Snapshots);
2. create a new disk : Compute > Compute Engine > Disks - new disk , select from snapshot in step 1 > **below that you can specify the new size in GB** ;
3. create a new VM instance and choose Existing Disk (make sure the disk is in the same zone 
   as the instance you are creating) and select the disk one from step 2;
4. SSH to your instance and follow steps 4-13 from [Repartitioning a root persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#repartitionrootpd).

You should now have an exact replica of your previous machine, but with a bigger HDD. Let me know if you see any issues.

Comment: On going through the steps while running (step3 and step 11) with command  gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE --zone us-central1-a  I got I got Error "some requests did not succeed -Insufficient Permission". Although i am able to increase my size.Does it affects any?

Comment: Just make sure you have the zone correctly when SSH´ing. It is not necessary to add --zone us-central1-a , you should get a prompt asking you for the zone. You can also check by running :

Comment: try running "gcloud auth login" and then "gcloud config set project your_project_name" and that should do the trick to SSH

Comment: when running gcloud auth login it asks verification code.What problem may arise if i dont do ssh .Though i am able to login to compute engine from putty though there was previous error in sshing

Comment: no issues whatsoever, it´s up to you how you want to connect to your instances

Comment: in case you are wondering, this is the "How To" page from Google: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/    . There are a lot of advantages of using the gcloud utilities, it makes administration a lot easier.

Comment: There is not steps in between  4-13

Answer (score 25):

**Update disk size on the fly without restarts**

1. Increase disk size from **Google** console first
2. SSH inside VM : `sudo growpart /dev/sda 1`
3. Resize your file system : `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`
4. Verify : `df -h`

Comment: nice, this answer should have been chosen

Comment: @Pratik Glad to hear that.

Comment: I am unable to resize my partitions because I can't even browser ssh into my VM. Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: There due to disk you are not able to access the instance on this case you can try using serial port something option in GCP to access the instance if not just restart your instance and try accessing it over the SSH.

Comment: I recieve `sudo: growpart: command not found` why?

Answer (score 4):

Now you can increase size of a Persistent Disk in place (beta feature):

```
gcloud beta compute disks resize DISK_NAME [DISK_NAME …] --size SIZE [--zone ZONE]
```

It works even of disk is attached and being used.
This would only re-size physical device. file system (and possibly partitions still need to adjusted after that)

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/disks/resize

Comment: I get this "ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.disks.resize) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission" when trying to use the resize command.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: What's the exact command, that results in  "Insufficient Permission"  ?  Could you also provide results of "gcloud compute disks list"  does "gcloud beta compute disks list"  produces the same result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps in Google Cloud Console:

1. In "Disk", expand the disk size into what you want.
2. Restart your instance.

Then you can check by `df -kh` and see your disk has been resized automatically.

Comment: This is what I did. Get hard disk size updated but from the ubuntu server it stays the same with old hard disk size.

Comment: @NamGVU In my case did work with a Balanced Disk (SSD)

Answer (score 0):

For disks without partition, these steps worked :

1. Increase disk size from Google console first
2. SSH in VM and check partitioning ( no need to unmount disk ) : `sudo lsblk`
3. If no partition, then run `resize2fs /dev/<device>`
4. `df -h` and voilà !

**Note** : If partitioned then follow Harsh [Manvar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60543233/248616).